# How to Enable or disable textbox based on condidtion

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
          <%= Html.TextBox("txtWeight", EmployeeInformation.Weight, new { style = "font-family:Verdana;font-size:9px;", @onfocus = "this.value=''", @onmouseover = "jsWeight()",  @readonly= (ViewData["flag"].ToString().CompareTo("true")==0 ? true : false) })%>
```

or

```
           <%= Html.TextBox("txtWeight", EmployeeInformation.Weight, new { style = "font-family:Verdana;font-size:9px;", @onfocus = "this.value=''", @onmouseover = "jsWeight()",  @readonly= ViewData["flag"].ToString()) })%>
```

The above code I m using to display information in textbox, as you can see I m using a onFocus and onMouseover so that I can show data in tooltip, and I m using @readonly to make sure textbox can be or cannot be edited based on condidtion.
But this is not working for me.
I have checked viewData's value that is ok.It is as I m passing to it.
I have tried using Disable as well but when I m using Disabled I get the value as disabled every time
and when I m using disable my on foucs event is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on `@readonly` and `@disabled` as they essentially make fields readonly or disabled simply by being present.  Although the correct syntax should be:

```
<input readonly="readonly" />
<input disabled="disabled" />
```

The same result can be achieved with:

```
<input readonly="" />
<input disabled="" />
```

Or simply:

```
<input readonly />
<input disabled />
```

It's better to omit these attributes completely if you don't want the fields to be readonly or disabled.

Comment: How to use this and fill data.
The code that I have given contain EmployeeInformation.Weight this is the data that I want to fill with textbox can u tell  me how to use this as well